# Issue Preparing MediaPlayer to play custom file

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, media, illegalstateexception

So basically everything works fine when I'm playing audio from the file included with the application in the res/raw folder, but when I want a user to pick their own file, I'm having troubles.

The object is to have the datasource for the media player set to the URI of the user's chosen file. Then to initialize the player with the new datasource and play it. My error comes when the the play method is invoked. It ends up saying I called play in an illegal state (i.e. I didn't prepare the player beforehand) but it's definitely prepared. What is happening and how can I fix it?

Invoked method to choose file:

```
public void chooseFile(){
    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("audio/mpeg");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, chosenAudioFilePath), 1);
}
```

Activity result method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED){
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if ((data != null) && (data.getData() != null)){
            userChosenFilePath = data.getData();
            setSongToUserPick();

            }
        }
}}
```

setSongToUserPick method:

```
public void setSongToUserPick(){
    stop();
    currentAudioPath = userChosenFilePath;
    initializePlayer();
    stopped = false;
    play();
}
```

Stop method:

```
public void stop() {
    isPlaying = false;
    stopped = true;
    playPauseButton.setText("Play");
    player.stop();
    player.release();
}
```

Initialize Player method:

```
public void initializePlayer() {


    nowPlayingView.setText(FilenameUtils.getBaseName(currentAudioPath.toString()));

    try {
        player.setDataSource(thisContext, currentAudioPath);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException
            | IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        player.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and finally, Play method:

```
public void play() {
    if(isPrepared){
    isPlaying = true;
    playPauseButton.setText("Pause");
    player.start();
    }else{
        System.out.println("Ahhh shit it broke.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this if it helps you out:

```
if(currentAudioPath!=null)
    player = MediaPlayer.create(thisContext, Uri.parse(currentAudioPath.toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onPreparedListener on your player. In which you use play() method.
Also use onCompleteListener on your player because whats happening right now is that 
all the things that you do are happening simultaneously and that's what causing the problem.

```
public void play() {
        player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        player.setDataSource(uri);
        player.prepareAsync();
}


@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if (!mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.start();
    }
}
```